# Why does an incorrect syntax error near appears?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error that Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.

```
SELECT   S.NAME, SUM([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS SALES
FROM    Invoices$ Inv INNER JOIN InvDetails$ InvD ON 
Inv.INVOICE_ID=InvD.INVOICE_ID
      INNER JOIN Products$ P ON InvD.PRODUCT_ID=P.PRODUCT_ID
    INNER JOIN Stores$ S ON S.STORE_ID=Inv.STORE_ID
GROUP BY SALES DESC
```

The expected result is to print  all stores and their sales sorted by total sales(SALES) in desecding order

Comment: Did you mean to do `GROUP BY S.NAME ORDER BY SALES DESC`?

Comment: You need an ORDER BY to use DESC.

Answer (score 3):

You mean to `GROUP BY S.NAME`, not `SALES`.

Also `GROUP BY` does not care about order, so move `DESC` to after the `ORDER BY`. You can't combine `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` into a single clause.

```
GROUP BY S.NAME 
ORDER BY SALES DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You query should look like this:

```
SELECT S.NAME, SUM([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS SALES
FROM Invoices$ Inv INNER JOIN
     InvDetails$ InvD
     ON Inv.INVOICE_ID = InvD.INVOICE_ID INNER JOIN
     Products$ P
     ON InvD.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID INNER JOIN
     Stores$ S
     ON S.STORE_ID = Inv.STORE_ID
GROUP BY S.NAME
ORDER BY SALES DESC;
```

`DESC` is supported as a keyword for `GROUP BY` in MySQL (although I think that usage has been deprecated in v8).  However, that is an extension not used by other databases.

In any case, the `GROUP BY` should contain all the non-aggregated keys in the `SELECT`.  That would be `S.NAME`, not `SALES`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `name` column add in `group by`

```
SELECT   S.NAME, SUM([QTY] * [PRICE]) AS SALES
    FROM    Invoices$ Inv INNER JOIN InvDetails$ InvD ON 
    Inv.INVOICE_ID=InvD.INVOICE_ID
          INNER JOIN Products$ P ON InvD.PRODUCT_ID=P.PRODUCT_ID
        INNER JOIN Stores$ S ON S.STORE_ID=Inv.STORE_ID
    GROUP BY S.NAME order by SALES desc
```